# How round calculated number in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, rounding

I have a *ngFor loop and want to calculate a value - with 2 decimal places.

The calculation works:

```html
 {{ ((date | amDifference : item.startdate : 'minutes' :true)/item.duration*100)  }}
```

But how can I round? I tryed like this:

```html
 {{ num | ((date | amDifference : item.startdate : 'minutes' :true)/item.duration*100) : '1.2-2' }}
```

But this create error:

zone.js:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token (, expected identifier or keyword at column 8 in [
                        {{ num | ((date | amDifference : item.startdate : 'minutes' :true)/item.duration*100) : '1.2-2' }}

Comment: The question is discussed [on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389227/deleted-question)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need another pipe to do this

```
import {Pipe} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe({name: 'round'})
export class RoundPipe {
  transform (input:number) {
    return Math.floor(input);
  }
}
```

template:

```
{{ date | amDifference : item.startdate : 'minutes' : true | round }}
```

Comment: Thank you! I created a round.pipe.ts and import this in app.module.ts  import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';
but I get error "The pipe 'round' could not be found"

Comment: Make sure you put it in `declarations` of app.module.ts

Comment: Oh perfekt, that was the mistake. It works, great. Thank you so much!

Comment: Math.floor will not round IMHO... use Math.round instead

Answer (score 25):

One can use angular built-in pipe such as [number](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe#parameters)

`{{value | number:'1.0-0'}}`

If one wants to have an implementation of it:

```
@Pipe({name: 'round'})
export class RoundPipe {
  transform (input:number) {
    return Math.floor(input);
  }
}
```

Use in the template

```
{{1,1 | round}} => 1
{{2,1 | round}} => 2
```

Another useful pipe is a round ten :

```
@Pipe({name: 'roundTen'})
export class RoundTenPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number): number {
    return Math.round(value / 10) * 10;
  }
}
```

Use in the template

```
{{11 | roundTen}} => 10
{{21 | roundTen}} => 20
```

Comment: I used the same built-in pipe with number: '1.0-0'. given 8.5 and suprisingly the rounded value is 9

Answer (score 12):

IF its CURRENCY `{{value | currency:'INR':true: '1.0-0'}}`

IF need NUMBER only `{{value | number:'1.0-0'}}`

1.0-0 means: at least one digit before decimal point, 0 digits after decimal point.

https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe

Answer (score 2):

For 1 decimal place:

```
{{value | number:'1.0-1'}}
```