# Angular4 - Calculation in style bindings

Tags: angular, binding, styles, target, calculation

Is there anyway you can do calculation in the style binding target in Angular4 ?

I've tried

```
[style.width]="{{1+1}}"

[style.width]="{{1+1}}px"

[style.width]="{{1px+1px}}"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `[style.width.px]="1 + 1"` in order to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks, do you also perhaps know how to round a number in Angular4 bindings?

Comment: there is a [built-in pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe) for that, but maybe you'll need to create your own pipe like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027749/angular-2-how-round-calculated-number)

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
   [style.width]="1+1+'px'"
```

Basically, when you're using `[]` , the must be expression and you should never put `{{}}` in the value, and this is a general Angular2 rule when you're using attribute binding.

```
[style.width]="{{1+1}}"   is wrong because of `{{}}` in the value
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[style.height.px]="200"
[style.height.px]="200 + 50"
[style.height.px]="_commonService.screenHeight"
[style.height.px]="_commonService.screenHeight + 50"
[style.height.px]="_commonService.screenHeight - (isHomePage == true?80:140)"
/* Other Examples **/
[ngStyle]="{'margin-top': isHomePage == true ? '0px' : '60px' }"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid doing style calculation inside your view. Simply create a function to handle this calculation and only return the result in view.

Comment: Please provide some sort of code description to improve this answer.